# Search View not collapsing properly

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

My search view is stuck on the right side replacing the toolbar's title when collapsed.

Before Opening:
[image: Before opening the search view]
After Closing:
[image: After opening and closing the search view]

Menu File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
      android:id="@+id/search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      android:title="@android:string/search_go"
      app:actionLayout="@layout/full_width_search_view"
      app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/btn_create"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
      android:title="@string/create"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
      android:title="@string/remove"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Full-Width Search View (which obviously is not working...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Activity's Code:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
  menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_create_delete, menu)

  // Handle Searching
  val searchView: SearchView = menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as SearchView
  searchView.isIconified = false
  searchView.clearFocus()

  menu.findItem(R.id.btn_delete).isVisible = orderLine.hasCustomer()

  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `onBackPressed()` method because you can collapse the `SearchView` by pressing the back button or back button in ActionBar

If you press the back button then:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (!searchView.isIconified) {
        searchView.isIconified == true;
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

If you press the ActionBar back button then you have to override the onOptionsItemSelected() method and then you have to do it in the same way given above.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my problem is that the icon of the SearchView when collapsed is stuck on the left side instead of moving back again to the right side

Answer (score 0):

I've already fixed it by removing `collapseActionView` and `searchView.isIconified = false`

Menu File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@android:string/search_go"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_create"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/create"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/remove"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Activity's Code:

```
  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_create_delete, menu)

    // Handle Searching
    val searchView: SearchView = menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as SearchView
    searchView.queryHint = "Search Partner..."
    // ...

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
  }
```